# How to fix missing JFrame library/class?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, extends, netbeans-8.2

As seen in screenshot 1, NetBeans (v8.2) does not recognise JFrame when extended (this is how NetBeans generated the file, which worked fine on another computer). As seen in screenshot 2, JFrame does not appear in the package list.

I have tried:

1. Creating a new project
2. Changing the line to `extends JFrame`
3. Restarting IDE
4. Reinstalling IDE
5. Googling a lot (no one else seems to have this issue)
6. Listed the bug at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-905

Any ideas?

Screenshot 1:
[image: Screenshot 1]

Screenshot 2:
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Are you using a Java standard library that came packaged with NetBeans, or a separate one?  If the latter, then obtain and install a fresh copy of *that*.

Comment: I just set up NetBeans on this computer, I installed NetBeans and the 64 bit JDK 8. I assume these libraries come from the JDK? As far as I know I have not installed any seperate libraries.

Comment: Yes, the standard library is included in the JDK (and also in JREs), but you can use either a separately installed JDK or one bundled with NetBeans.

Comment: Well as far as I know it will be from the installed JDK (NetBeans required me to install it first) but even so it doesn't explain my problem because all other libraries appear to be there. So what should I do? Reinstall JDK?

Comment: I can't be confident about the nature of the problem, but downloading a fresh copy of the JDK, removing the old one, and installing the new one is a plausible solution that you don't describe having tried yet.  That may require reinstalling NetBeans afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed a suggestion from Laszlo Kishalmi at issues.apache.org:

1. Went to Help -> About in NetBeans.
2. Copied filepath for cache folder in "About" window, closed NetBeans.
3. Browsed the folder, deleted it.
4. Re-opened NetBeans and the issue was solved.

Sorted!